# RecyclerView - can't resolve GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I'm using the RecyclerView support library v21, and targeting SDK 21, but Android Studio can't seem to resolve GridLayoutManager.  LinearLayoutManager is fine.  What am I doing wrong?

When I go to the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html , the class's package is listed as android.support.v7.widget

I have this line in my build.gradle file:

```
'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to update my support repo.